# Javascript Error in FireFox Not in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, validation, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following function for decimal validation.the textbox only allow to enter numbers and .(dot) symbol only.It was working fine in IE and Chrome.My problem is I get **event is not defined error**.How to solve this?I have the lot of textbox validation.so i Create the decimal validation as common its like,

```
//Call the Function
                             $('.decimalValidate').live('keypress',function(){
                                  var decimalid=$(this).attr("id");
                                  var decimalval=$('#'+decimalid).val();
                                  var decimalvalidate=ApplyDecimalFilter(decimalval);
                                  if(decimalvalidate == false)
                                  return false;
                             });
```

//Function for Decimal validation.It allows only one . symbol.everything works fine on IE and Chrome

```
function ApplyDecimalFilter(id)
    {
        try {
              return NewDecimalFilter(id, event);

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    }

function NewDecimalFilter(o, event) {

        if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) && o.indexOf('.') == -1)  {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And i use this decimalValidate class in text box like as,

```
input type="text" id="InputLoanAmount" class="decimalValidate" style="width:100px"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: event is not defined error in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox)

Answer (score 5):

In firefox, `event` isn't global. `window.event` is `undefined`. You need to pass the event as a parameter. And by the way, you should use `.on` instead of `.live` if you use jQuery >= 1.7.

```
$('.decimalValidate').live('keypress', function (e) {
    var decimalid = $(this).attr("id");
    var decimalval = $('#' + decimalid).val();
    var decimalvalidate = ApplyDecimalFilter(decimalval, e);
    if (decimalvalidate == false) return false;
});

function ApplyDecimalFilter(id, event) {
    try {
        return NewDecimalFilter(id, event);

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

***[The live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DN7zE/8/)***.

Comment: this case work in IE and Chrome.But i cant enter any character in that text box using firefox

Comment: FireFox didn't allow to enter the character in textbox

Comment: @user What do you mean of it? Can you give a demo?

Comment: I use your Idea then i run My application in firefox i cant able to enter anything in textbox

Comment: @user You should use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode`, try again *)

Comment: I use event.which but still the problem is continue.I think the if condition is a problem i put alert in the if condition it will show in IE and Chrome when I enter the text.But FF doesn't show the alert message

Comment: @user I have added the demo, just check it.

Comment: How to check can you send me the link because am new to jsfiddle

Comment: How to check can you send me the link because am new to jsfiddle

Comment: @user See my answer, I added the link.

Comment: @user Please do some effect yourself. And the backspace is working.