# Event variable set even if not in parameters

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Given the following code:

```
openUserProfile: function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    // Rest of function
}
```

In Firefox, it throws `ReferenceError: event is not defined` as expected, because `event` is not passed in as a parameter. However in Chrome and Safari, `event` is defined and thus the code above runs fine.

Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through this thread; `window.event` is not defined in FF

[Javascript Error in FireFox Not in IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256257/javascript-error-in-firefox-not-in-ie-and-chrome)

Instead try this:-

```
openUserProfile: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Rest of function
}
```