# jquery line of code not working with with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

i have this line of code it works in google chrome but not in mozilla firefox.

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(){  
  event.returnValue = false; 
  if( i > 1 ){ 
    $(this).parents('span').remove();
    i--; 
  } 
});
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Use `document`, instead of `"body"` like this `$(document).on("click",..`

Comment: then pass `event` in `function`, like `function(event)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass event to the function like so:

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(event){ 
   event.returnValue = false;
   if( i > 1 ){ 
       $(this).parents('span').remove();
       i--;
   }
});
```

[More info in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox)

Comment: it a line o code to delete an input of file in chrome it works but on firefox when i click the delete button the page refresh

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to modify 
    getPreventDefaul() 
with 
    defaultPrevented() 
on jquery.js
and

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(){  
event.returnValue = false; 
if( i > 1 ){ 
$(this).parents('span').remove();
i--; 
} 
});
```

with

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(event){  
event.returnValue = false;
if( i > 1 ){ 
$(this).parents('span').remove();
i--; 
} 
});
```