# How come you can access 'event' without passing it in args when using ES6 Arrow functions + Babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've just stumbled upon something which I think shouldn't be correct.

The code below should not work, as event is not being passed in the args:

```
var myFunc() {console.log(event.target.value)}
```

But with arrow functions using Babel to transpile from ES6, the following works

```
() => {console.log(event.target.value)}
```

Why should the latter work?

A more specific example can be found at line 43 of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Samlilli/163c6b5eb776adc311cbb32d9dd73c5f), where I'm using react and Babel to transpile ES6 - remove `event` from the args and it still works as expected.

Comment: Those should behave the same (for this example), but you haven't given us a reproducible example, so it's impossible to say what the issue is.

Comment: Why shouldn't the first one work (if it was valid code)? As long as `event` is available in the surrounding scope the function can access it.

Comment: Take this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Samlilli/163c6b5eb776adc311cbb32d9dd73c5f) at line 43, and remove 'event' from the arg - it still works

Comment: Please trim down the example to a few lines. I cannot run that, so I cannot verify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer (not sure if all versions) events are passed via window.event. So if you use IE when you remove event from arguments list you can still reference global event object.

**Edit**: Actually it is also available in other browsers. I just tested it in Chrome. I am not sure which browsers exactly support this property.

Comment: Notably [not Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20522887/1048572).