# jQuery event handler and undeclared event object

Tags: javascript

I ran into a weird situation debugging somebody's code. The code below is a demonstration of the issue.

My impression is that `event` should be `undefined` when entering the event handler. It's like that in Firefox but in Chrome and IE11 `event` is not `undefined`, instead containing the event object. My guess is that a closure is in effect somehow but not when in Firefox.

Which way is it supposed to work? Where does the blame for the inconsistency lie (jQuery? Firefox? Chrome/IE11?)?

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  $(event.target).css({backgroundColor:color});
  $('body').css({backgroundColor:color});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Is there a parent event of some sort that's using it's event? Is the event tied to the button click? iirc `event` should be undefined because it isn't implicitely passed to the callback

Comment: Now that I know what I'm looking for, MDN's article on [window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) gives the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some browsers the event is actually globally defined, `window.event`, which just refers to the last event. In others, it needs to be explicitly passed. You can *always* pass it as the first argument I believe (I know I ran into this not that long ago and *think* this is the solution I used).

If you want to be really safe, you could always pass it and then do `event = event || window.event` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a duplicate of this question: [ReferenceError: event is not defined error in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox)

Basically Chrome, IE and Safari have a global symbol for events, Firefox doesn't. As best practice, you should always provide the paramter `event` or `e` or `whatever` to normalize behaviour between browsers