# Function Event Target in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to get "event.target" to work and cannot. Check out the fiddle below. It works in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox. I get nothing there.

```
mySpan.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){ textClick(); }, false)

function textClick (){
    outPutBox.innerHTML = event.target.textContent
}
```

Here's the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmperkins74/ochvvn0o/

In the FF console, it says "event is not defined" but why is it working in the other browsers?

I'm quite a rookie, so please be gentle. Any help appreciated. Also, please don't throw any JQuery my way... I'm just not "there" yet.

Thanks,
Dan P.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: event is not defined error in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because event is not defined. It is passed from the event listener.

```
mySpan.addEventListener('mouseup', textClick, false)

function textClick (event) {
    outPutBox.innerHTML = event.target.textContent
}
```

or

```
mySpan.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){ textClick(e); }, false)

function textClick (event) {
    outPutBox.innerHTML = event.target.textContent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)