# Firefox Throws error with this js code(ReferenceError: event is not defined) need fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

In chrome: if i excute this code(javascript)

```
 function abc(event){
      console.log('hello: '+event);
    }
abc(event);
```

the above code gives output as :
"hello:undefined"

but same code if we excute in firefox we get error
what is the simple solution for this.

Comment: But it's not really clear what you expect... The variable `event` doesn't exist when you call `abc`.

Comment: I know RefrenceError event is not defined in firefox passing paramerter also does not fixed it.

Comment: Not all browsers have a global `event`, hence it is `undefined` for those browsers and not for the others.

Comment: The simple solution is to not use references that aren't defined.

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha i need same output as chrome in firefox

Comment: @VishalPatil You're asking for the two different browsers to work the same? Good luck with that.

Comment: Browser not work as per your requirement. You need to write correct code.

Comment: @  vi5ion yes i know that we should not use this but actually i need event in firefox as in my project i have given it functionality based on event variable.

Comment: Usually when using an `event` in a function, that means the function is actually triggered by an `event` like `click` or `change`. When setting the eventlistener you have the `event` there and you can pass it to another function.

Comment: i guess you should just do something like abc(this.event) but it's kinda ridiculous

Comment: The solution what i have read is that we need to pass event as parameter in many links.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox

Comment: But when you do that, you pass the function as event handler, not call it yourself. If you want to manually invoke the event, you need to construct an event object first and pass that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event happening in your script to track. You are simply calling a method and passing it a property.

If you want to grab "event" then you have to have to create an event.

Example:
This is a click event in jQuery.

```
$(sometarget).click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```