# Vuejs event not working in firefox - fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an event in vuejs

```
methods: {
   filterPeople: function filterPeople() {
      $(event.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

In firefox I get an error

```
TypeError: event is undefined
mounted/<
re/e.prototype.$emit
filterPeople
```

Any idea why this does not work in FF

Comment: I presume this contains copy/paste mistake, your brackets/semicolons are invalid js.

Comment: You have a very obvious syntax error. There is a `)` with no matching `(`, and an opening `{` that is never closed.

Comment: I am using the vuejs to emit the even

Answer (score 5):

Firefox [doesn't have a global event object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20522980/38065).

> WebKit follows IE's old behavior of using a global symbol for "event",
>   but Firefox doesn't.

Simply add it as a parameter.

```
methods: {
  filterPeople: function filterPeople(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the `event` as parameter, should be :

```
methods: {
  filterPeople: function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

**NOTE :** The name was duplicated in the function definition.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pass event to function filterPeople(). Like this:

```
methods: {
  filterPeople: function filterPeople (e) {
  $(e.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```