# AngularJS - Firefox error - event is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I am using Angular v1.6.3 and after form submitting (I am not sure that is the reason) this error appears:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Full error log:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
e/<()angular.min.js (line 123)
zf/this.$get</<()angular.min.js (line 95)
Mf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply()angular.min.js (line 149)
Zc[b]</<.compile/</<()angular.min.js (line 285)
b.event.dispatch()jquery-1.7.2.js (line 1)
b.event.add/bB()jquery-1.7.2.js (line 1)


...ly(b,a)}:function(a,b){e(a,null==b?"":b)}}var f=za||/\bEdge\//.test(d.navigator&...

angular.min.js (line 123)
```

It only happens in Firefox version 42+ (almost all 42+). If there are more details needed just comment them. Thanks.

Comment: Are any handlers missing an event parameter?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Checkig...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you use a function by parameter that call to "event".you must pass $event argument in called function in view