# JS not function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, alert

I tries to used this code to make an alert when user click on the link. However, this function only work with Chrome and Internet Explorer but doesn't work in Firefox.

Please refer to the code below :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".disableGA").on("click", function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Google Analytics was disabled");
      window.location.href = 'javascript:gaOptout()';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="disableGA">Disable Google Analytics</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please pass `event` to the function and try again

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".disableGA").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Google Analytics was disabled");
        window.location.href='javascript:gaOptout()';
    });
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast respond. But it still doesn't work with Firefox browser. I've test with other browser, everything was fine

Comment: It works for me. Can you check your console and tell what error are you getting ?

Comment: I get this error
ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: @user3103783 `$(".disableGA").on("click", function(event){` check this line. You might be missing `event` in your code.

Comment: @user3103783 you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20522887/1848140). I am pretty sure this is the same issue you are facing