# Firefox troubles with concrete custom select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a custom select box which Firefox cannot interact. Does anyone understand what is the problem ? I guess the problem is in the code below:

```
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $('html').one('click',function() {
        $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The select box is here: https://codepen.io/yy/pen/vOYqYV

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522887/referenceerror-event-is-not-defined-error-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReferenceError: event is not defined` error is showing in the firefox console. this means you are using `event` which is not defined. so rewrite the code as follows

```
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function(event) {//added event here
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[DEMO HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmaPvd)

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console, it says `event not defined`.

Here `$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {` you need to add `event`, so it says `$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function(event) {`

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".custom-select-trigger").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
});
```